# Multiple ajax requests or one shot?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, asp.net-ajax

I encounter some design problems.
I have a page with a JQuery Calendar (full-calendar) and I need to retrieve two IDs depending on the current month.
Which is the best solution ?

1. Retrieve the IDs using an Ajax Request each time the calendar is re-rendered (the month changed)
2. Loading all the Ids (I use Asp.Net Mvc) once and then filtering.

I tried to use the first solution but when the user switch the month too fast (January to February per example), it affects January IDs to February because the user switched too fast (before the first requests actually finished).

Hope I'm clear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: APIs should be very specific at getting resources. So I would always fire off multiple requests rather than trying to bulk load information... If I am firing over 20 requests in one go, I generally try and rethink the page, it may not be the best UI

Comment: So how you doing when these requests depends on a js event (changing month) ?

Comment: In that case you can spread out the amount of requests, so I would still make them very specific. You can use Promises to chain up requests as well, so if one depends on another to have finished.

Comment: My problem is if I make a request for January and switch too fast to February, February will have January Ids because January request won't have enough time to complete.

Comment: Then have some kind of delay or disable the control for a moment to prevent switching too fast

Comment: Yeah you usually put up a "curtain" (transparent black div over everything) whilst it's loading the main stuff, or you can go a lot more granular to the controls like Bon said

Comment: Ok I see.
Is it a good practice (not good, I know it's bad) to set async to false so it won't let the user switch or do anything before the ajax is executed ?

Comment: you can add a loader on By enabling in ajaxStart and disabling in ajxStop. 
cause thats what i am doing if you want do this way i can write down the code its simple

Comment: Thanks.
What I chose to do is to initialize an array where I put all the needToCancel ajax requests and created a cancelAjaxRequests method that I call each time I change the month.

Answer (score 0):

The First Method is prefereable. What you can do is add a time disable ,for me a loader is of best usage in this type of situations

Css :

```
body.loading {
overflow: hidden;   
}

body.loading .modal1 {
display: block;
 }
 .modal1 {
 display:    none;
 position:   fixed;
 z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
     left:       0;
height:     100%;
width:      100%;
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
            url('Loaderurl') 
            50% 50% 
            no-repeat;
  }
```

View -
   add this at bottom

```
    <div class="modal1"></div>
```

Script-

```
 $body = $("body");
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () {

        $body.addClass("loading");
    },
    ajaxStop: function (e) { 

       $body.removeClass("loading");
    }
 });
```

Comment: The problem with this method (for my case) is that if the user wants to switch from January to December, he will have to wait every time.
For a matter of UX, I will keep my method but thanks a lot :)

Comment: if you are unable to solve your prob .then if you could share your code i could be of more help cause , i agree scenarios do matter .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
What I chose to do is to initialize an array where I put all the needToCancel ajax requests and created a cancelAjaxRequests method that I call each time I change the month.

```
var lastMonthAjaxRequests = [];
lastMonthAjaxRequests.push(... my ajax requests...)
function abortAjaxRequests(ajaxRequests) {
            $.each(ajaxRequests,
                function() {
                    this.abort();
                });
        }
```

Then each time my calendar is re-rendered :

```
abortAjaxRequests(lastMonthAjaxRequests);
lastMonthAjaxRequests = [];
```